# Long tail where clause at CodeIgniter or Ignited Datatables

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datatables, where-clause

I am trying to write a long tail `where` statement which containing another select query and how I can do it. Currently, I am using Ignited Datatables Library with my CodeIgniter 3 installation.

```
SELECT ContactId,
       ReceiverId,
       SenderId,
       IF(ReceiverId = 1,
            (SELECT first_name
             FROM users
             WHERE users.id = contacts_connectivity.SenderId),
            (SELECT first_name
             FROM users
             WHERE users.id = contacts_connectivity.ReceiverId)) AS FirstName,
       IF(ReceiverId = 1,
            (SELECT email
             FROM users
             WHERE users.id = contacts_connectivity.SenderId),
            (SELECT email
             FROM users
             WHERE users.id = contacts_connectivity.ReceiverId)) AS SenderEmail,
       IF(ReceiverId = 1,
            (SELECT phone
             FROM users
             WHERE users.id = contacts_connectivity.SenderId),
            (SELECT phone
             FROM users
             WHERE users.id = contacts_connectivity.ReceiverId)) AS SenderPhone,
       IF(ReceiverId = 1,
            (SELECT company
             FROM users
             WHERE users.id = contacts_connectivity.SenderId),
            (SELECT company
             FROM users
             WHERE users.id = contacts_connectivity.ReceiverId)) AS SenderCompany,
       ModulesId,

  (SELECT ModuleName
   FROM modules
   WHERE ModuleId = contacts_connectivity.ModulesId) AS ModuledName,
       FROM_UNIXTIME(AddedDate, "%m/%d/%Y") AddedDate
FROM contacts_connectivity
WHERE (ReceiverId = 1
       OR SenderId = 1)
  AND (ReceiverId
       OR SenderId NOT IN
         (SELECT (ReceiverId
                  OR SenderId)
          FROM contacts_connectivity
          WHERE (ReceiverId
                 OR SenderId) = 1))
```

I noticed that My query doesn't return any array at all. I already tried to write the where statement like this-

```
$this->datatables->where("(ReceiverId = ' . $id . ' OR SenderId = ' . $id . ')");
$this->datatables->where(" AND (ReceiverId OR SenderId NOT IN (SELECT (ReceiverId OR SenderId) FROM contacts_connectivity WHERE (ReceiverId OR SenderId) = ' . $id . '");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You invalid use parameters. Try something like this:

```
$this->datatables->where("(ReceiverId=$id OR SenderId=$id )");
```

Second string should be fixed too the same way. Also check that your `$id` param properly escaped.

Comment: What about the following script `$this->datatables->where(" AND (ReceiverId OR SenderId NOT IN (SELECT (ReceiverId OR SenderId) FROM contacts_connectivity WHERE (ReceiverId OR SenderId) = $id");`